# How to know, who made request?

Tags: php, request, http-referer

How to know, who made `POST` request to my server?

Other server makes `POST` request to my servers `API -> My server` looks up who made this request. ( hostname )

Answer (score 6):

You can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` for the server IP from which request is made.

Comment: Ahh, indeed.

As I was testing this on my local environment and it returned 127.0.0.1, at first I thought this returned my API servers address, but yeah, looks like this is what I need.

I also found this function which returns hostname for ip address -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple answers to this one.

As @Nick mentioned, there is the ip address that the request came from.

There is also the browser - this is also in the $_SERVER header.

If you want to know more, then you might need some sort of "password" to use your server - often called a "token", which uniquely identifies the requesting server - no token, no service. Then you will know.

Comment: Thanks.

I'm already using tokens.

I thought that checking for servers host would be a good additional security. Looks like there is no 100% secure safe, trustworthly method to do that?

Comment: anything other than a secret or an ip address is very easily fakeable. You could use public/private keypair (e.g. https client authentication) but if you assume that the attacker has access to any data on the server (e.g. token, private key) then there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is hitting your API, you can always get details using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. You can also use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. "-". $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` to pin point and track with more efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for answers.

Thanks to Nick I was able to get servers IP address. I went further and found this function -> gethostbyaddr()

This is what I initially wanted:

( taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php )

`$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);`

Hope this helps someone, as I didn't knew about this function before.

Comment: Be warned - gethostbyaddr is easy to falsify.